# Poorly typeset μ symbol in plotmath

Tags: r, plot, fonts, plotmath, typesetting

When using the default font (`sans`) in base R, symbols like μ are poorly typeset:

```r
plot(1, xlab = bquote("I want sans font here, but serif font for:" ~ (mu * g)))
```

[image: sans]

The *g* looks larger than the *μ* symbol.

Setting the font family to `serif` somewhat improves this:

```r
par(family = "serif)
plot(1, xlab = bquote("I want sans font here, but serif font for:" ~ (mu * g)))
```

[image: serif]

Still not perfect, but much closer.

- If I want the text to be `sans`, is it possible to change the font family mid-sentence for the symbols?
- If not, is there a better way to typeset μg in `plot`?

Comment: check the `ragg` package....could be helpful.

Comment: @Roman wow, that is something I had been looking for for a long time, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If not, is there a better way to typeset μg in `plot`

As it turns out, there is indeed a far simpler way to get better typeset symbols:

```r
plot(1, xlab = "It turns out you can just use the character μ directly")
```

[image: μ]

If you save with the right encoding (here I used UTF-8), many symbols can just be used directly in R code and will be printed correctly.

I hope this answer can be useful to others.